# Find all possible values of a natural number $n$ such that $a! + b! = 5^n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial

I got the following problem:

> Find all possible values of a natural number n such that  $$ a! + b! = 5^n $$

**My solution**: 
Since $5^n$ is always an odd number, $a!$ needs to be odd and $b!$ to be even or vice-versa. The only possible value for $a$ then is 1, assuming $a\le b$. $$ 1 + b! = 5^n $$

I am not sure on how to proceed from here. My first guess was to try to find all possible values such that $$ n = \log_{5}(b!) $$ However I could not proceed further. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you see why $b<5$?

Comment: Note that for $b>4$, the sum always has $1$ in the units place. Now only three cases remain for you to check

Comment: @J.G. Yes, I see that. I assume that this is because b! is a multiple of 5.

Comment: @DatBoi, is this because n = for b>4, b! = 5*2*.. and therefore at the unit's digit there is 1 + 0 = 1? Or is there some other explanation as well?

Comment: Well if you've narrowed it down to $0 \leq b < 5$ then from there you can basically just check every possible value for b

Comment: Thanks everybody. Got the solution

Comment: @NaitikMundra nope, yours was perfect!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*note:* for $a\geq5$ and $b\geq5$ the last digits of $a!$ and $b!$ will be $0$ , giving the last digit of $a!+b!$ as $0$ . But , this will contradict that $a!+b!=5^n$ as $5^n$ have last digit as $5$ .

Hence $a<5$ and $b<5$ i.e. $(a,b)\in\{(1,1) , (2,2) , (3,3),(4,4),(1,2),(1,3),\color{red}{(1,4)},(2,1),(2,3),(2,4),(3,4)\}$ .

Among these only $(a,b)=(1,4)$ or $(4,1)$ satisfys the condition . $$1!+4!=5^2$$

Comment: You've jumped from them not both being $\ge5$ to their both not being $\ge5$, as opposed to exactly one being $\ge5$. The latter case also has to be excluded (which isn't hard).

Answer (score 4):

Wlog $a\le b$ so, working modulo $2$, $a\le1$ and $a!=1$. Then $5\nmid b!$ and $b\le4$. We can easily check the only solution is $b=4$, so $n=2$.

Answer (score 1):

Once you render $a!=1$, then $b!\equiv-1\bmod 5$. Since $5!$ and larger factorials are multiples of $5$ we must have $b\le4$, and then only $4!$ has the proper residue. So either $0!+4!=5^2$ or $1!+4!=5^2$, nothing more.